# ViewComponent not found after upgrading Monorail from v1.0.3 to v2.1RC

Tags: castle-monorail, nvelocity

I'm using Monorail in my C# web application. Since I upgrated it (.Net Framework 2 to 4 and Monorail 1.0.3 to 2.1RC), my ViewComponent class is not found. All my controllers seem to work fine. I'm using nVelocity View Engine. I'm not using Windsor, but maybe now I'm suppose to register it in a certain way?

In the .vm file, I experimented the following lines (without success, the first one was working before I upgraded the project) :

```
 #component(MenuComponent)
 #component(MenuComponent with "role=admins")
 #blockcomponent(MenuComponent with "role=admins")
```

Did anyone experiment that?

The full error message is:

> ViewComponent 'MenuComponent' could
>   not be found. Was it registered? If
>   you have enabled Windsor Integration,
>   then it's likely that you have forgot
>   to register the view component as a
>   Windsor component. If you are sure you
>   did it, then make sure the name used
>   is the component id or the key passed
>   to ViewComponentDetailsAttribute

Many thanks!

Comment: How do you register it in Windsor?

Comment: Sorry jishi, I'm not using Windsor so I can't help you. Maybe you can find some clue in that sample of code : http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users/browse_thread/thread/f8002e922dc04bee

Comment: Then how do you register components and controllers? I wasn't asking for me, I was asking in order to help you.

Comment: Ok, thanks ! I just don't register it, I supposed it was 'automatic', as in the previous version of Monorail, and the code I updated to fix it seems to confirm that. I just specified my assembly in the config file like that : <controllers><assembly>MyAssemblyName</assembly></controllers>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a clue to my problem. I used 'Castle.Monorail.Framework.dll' source code to see what happen inside : it seems that assemblies specified in the Web.Config file (in `<Controllers>` or even in `<viewcomponents>`) are not 'inspected' as they are supposed to be because the variable which contains it is initialized too late.

I builded a new version of the dll and now it's working fine. I will submit my 'fixed' code to the Castle Project Community to be sure it's not the consequence of something else (like bad settings).

Til then here is my 'fix', I just moved a portion of code. You can find the original source code here : http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/Default/Project/Castle/1.0-RC3/Debug/All/Castle.MonoRail.Framework/Castle.MonoRail.Framework/Services/DefaultViewComponentFactory.cs

```
*Assembly:* Castle.MonoRail.Framework
*Class:* Castle.MonoRail.Framework.Services.**DefaultViewComponentFactory**


public override void Service(IServiceProvider provider)
{
  /* Here is the section I moved */
  var config = (IMonoRailConfiguration)provider.GetService(typeof(IMonoRailConfiguration));
  if (config != null)
  {
    assemblies = config.ViewComponentsConfig.Assemblies;
    if (assemblies == null || assemblies.Length == 0)
    {
      // Convention: uses the controller assemblies in this case
      assemblies = config.ControllersConfig.Assemblies.ToArray();
    }
  }
  /*******************************/

  base.Service(provider); // Assemblies inspection is done there

  var loggerFactory = (ILoggerFactory) provider.GetService(typeof(ILoggerFactory));
  if (loggerFactory != null)
  {
    logger = loggerFactory.Create(typeof(DefaultViewComponentFactory));
  }
  /* The moved section was here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious, without your fix, if you rename MenuComponent to just Menu, does it work?